# Set::write error when using For loop

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-7

Solving a complicated formula `f(u,v)==0`, where

I assign some constant value to *u* and then solve *v*.

I *can* solve it *without* for-loop, but encounter errors by adding `For[]` enclosing the codes,

where saying

```
Set::write: Tag Times in "Solve[] with exact coefficients solns is Protected.
```

A simple example to illustrate my idea:

```
  For[  i = 1, i < 5, i++,

        f = x^2 + y^2 - 10;
        x = i;
        eqn = (f == 0);
        soln = Solve[eqn, y]

     ]
```

will get error:

```
Set::write: "Tag Times in (-9+y^2) is Protected."
```

*Only* when I add For[ ] at the outside of the code

(inner 4-line code works fine without for loop)

So it seems that there is an variable assignment permission issue in the for loop

How can I avoid it?

Comment: You're missing a `,` after `i++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer have Mathematica 7 installed, and your code runs (although with no printed output...) on Mathematica 10. Based on the error message, it sounds like you need to `Clear[f]` before trying to reassign it.

```
For[i = 1, i < 5, i++,
 Clear[f];
 f = x^2 + y^2 - 10;
 x = i;
 eqn = (f == 0);
 soln = Solve[eqn, y];
 Print[soln]
]
```

However, you're still really mixing things up. Consider what happens with your code as the loop executes. First it starts with i=1 and says:

- `Clear[f]` -- or don't, this isn't the only issue
- `f = x^2 + y^2 - 10` -- This gives me an expression with symbols `x` and `y`
- `x=i` -- This sets `x=1` since `i=1` already

At this point, **the expression for `f` has become y^2 - 9`**. Next time it comes around, it will repeat:

- `f = x^2 + y^2 - 10` -- But `x` is no longer a symbol!! So now it still treats `x=1`...

This becomes a nightmare. I could try to hack your code into working with the fewest changes (e.g. make it `Clear[f,x]` or something), but that's not really the best advice I can give.

A better overall construction would be something like:

```
Eqn[x_,y_]=(x^2+y^2-10==0);
For[i=1,i<5,i++,
 Print[Solve[Eqn[i,y],y]];
];
```

Your function `f` is a function, so you should make it a function like `f[x_,y_]=something`. Better yet, just make the entire equation into a function as above. That way, you never actually modify the values of `x` or `y` and don't get caught with issues in your loop.

And before you use this new code I've given you, clear everything or just quit the Kernel.